# Derivative of function composed with itself

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I don't know hot to differentiate a simple function composed with itself.

Let $f_{a}(x)$ be a function of $x$ and $a$:

$$f_{a}(x)=ax$$

Here $x$ will be always fixed (e.g. a point) and $a$ is considered parameter. The derivative with respect to $a$ is obviously $x$.

Now what about another derivative at $x$ with respect to $a$ of this function:

$$f_{a}(f_{a}(x))=f_{a}(ax)=a^{2}x$$

The derivative should be therefore:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}f_{a}(f_{a}(x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}a^{2}x=2ax$$

But using chain rule:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}f_{a}(f_{a}(x)) &= \frac{\partial f_{a}}{\partial f_{a}(x)}\cdot\frac{\partial f_{a}(x)}{\partial a} \\ &= \frac{\partial f_{a}}{\partial f_{a}(x)}\cdot x\end{align}$$

From this we know that $\frac{\partial f_{a}}{\partial f_{a}(x)}$ must be equal to $2a$. But how to get to this?

I know the chain rule is probably used improperly here. What rule applies in this case? Or how to restate the problem so that we can have such composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_a(x)=f(a,x)=ax$$
$$f_a(f_a(x))=f(a,f_a(x))=f(a,f(a,x))=af(a,x)=a^2x$$
$${\partial\over\partial a}f(a,x)={\partial(ax)\over\partial a}=x$$
$${\partial\over\partial x}f(a,x)={\partial(ax)\over\partial x}=a$$
$${\partial\over\partial a}f(a,f(a,x))={\partial\over\partial a}f(a,u)$$
where,$$u=f(a,x)=ax$$
Then:
$${\partial\over\partial a}f(a,u)={\partial(au)\over\partial a}+{\partial f(a,u)\over\partial u}{\partial u\over\partial a}=u+ax=ax+ax=2ax$$

Comment: Please where does the first element and the addition come from in this: ${\partial\over\partial a}f(a,u)={\partial(au)\over\partial a}+{\partial f(a,u)\over\partial u}{\partial u\over\partial a}$ ? I thought the chain rule is just multiplication of outer and inner function derivatives.

Comment: Oh, it is a multiple variable function, and then using chain rule. If you also substitute with $v=a$ it will make sense.

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right direction. I will take a look on multivariate chain rule tutorial then and hopefully grasp this concept.

Comment: No matter how I am trying I always end up with: ${\partial\over\partial a}f(a,u)={\partial au\over\partial a}={\partial  au\over\partial u}{\partial u\over\partial a}={\partial au\over \partial u}{\partial ax\over a}=a\cdot x=ax$

Comment: Finally, after lots of searching, if found this exact sample on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Differentiation_with_indirect_dependencies).

Comment: So you used total derivative while I was stuck with partials. Now I am getting clearer picture.

Comment: I saw the wiki. The key word is "independent". Here, $a$ and $u$ is not independent.

Comment: Let us start from here: $${\partial{au}\over\partial{u}}={\partial{a}\over\partial{u}}u+a{\partial{u}\over\partial{u}}=(1/x)(ax)+a=2a$$. This is done according to derivative of products.

Comment: How does ${\partial a\over \partial u}={1\over x}$ ? I understand it is just result of ${a\over ax}$, but why is this operation legal (removing partial signs and taking it as a fraction)? You said we cannot just simplify the fraction in the first place as $a$ and $u$ are dependent, but then we use product rule and to precisely this in the second step...

Comment: I think I got it. By considering the reciprocal of that and imagining the rates of change, it makes perfect sense. So finally a total derivative is not appropriate here, rather partial derivative applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the chian rule question the other way.

Given:
$$f_a(x)=ax$$
We have:
$${\partial{f_a(x)}\over\partial a}={\partial {(ax)}\over\partial a}=x$$
If we modify the original problem as this:
$$f_{f_a(x)}(x)=f_a(x)x=(ax)x=ax^2$$
Then:
$${\partial{f_{f_a(x)}(x)}\over\partial a}={\partial{f_{f_a(x)}(x)}\over\partial{f_a(x)}}{\partial{f_a(x)}\over\partial{a}}=xx=x^2$$

Comment: I think I need the first version. I saw several tutorials but still can't figure how the plus sign got in the derivative to get $2ax$. The chain rule has form $\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{b}{c}$ but had something like $d + \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{b}{c}$. But how the $d$ got in it?